# Jersey Spring 3 Integration is not working

Tags: spring, jersey

I want to migrate my simple spring rest project to jersey JAX-RS specs.
Following is code of project .

I am getting 404 error when invoke webservice from postman rest client

```
http://localhost:8080/jerseyproject/users/ping
```

Resource Class - UserController.java

```
@Component
@Path("/users")
public class UserController {

    private static List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response userList()
    {
        //HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        UserList users = new UserList();
        users.setUserList(userList);
        //return new ResponseEntity(users,headers,HttpStatus.OK);
        return (Response.status(200).entity(users)).build();
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response newUser(User user)
    {
        //HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        userList.add(user);
        return (Response.status(200).entity(user)).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String ping()
    {
        return "alive";
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>\WEB-INF\my-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.practice.controller</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

myServlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.practice.controller"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Resource Beans
User.java

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "userId",
    "userName",
    "userAge"
})
public class User {

    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String userId;
    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String userName;
    @JsonProperty("userAge")
    private int userAge;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public int getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }
    public void setUserAge(int userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }
}
```

UserList.java

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "users"
})
public class UserList {
    @JsonProperty("users")
    private List<User> userList;

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }
    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }
}
```

POM Dependancies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your web.xml the servlet mapping might be wrong. Use the below class in the mapping.

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
```

Comment: solved issue .. refered this link http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tutorial-rest-api-design-and-implementation-in-java-with-jersey-and-spring/